# Mesh unwrapping incorrectly to baked texture after using UV project

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, obj

This mesh previously had a texture baked to it. When I import it as a .obj and try to unwrap it using smart UV project, the mesh doesn't unwrap to the texture correctly. When I use unwrap, it is even worse. I do not have the ability to bake the textures due to hardware limitations. Can anybody help me with this?
[image]

Comment: When the texture was baked there must have been a UV map that fit the texture. Rebaking it with some automatic settings will most likely not give the same result. The texture is just an image with coloured pixels, it holds absolutely no information for Blender how the UVs should be placed - you can only do it visually by guessing.